# Image(BLOB) Not Perfectly Saving Images In Database

Tags: php, database, image, upload, blob

I am trying to upload images to my database so for this I created a table as below.

[image]

And using the below PHP code to upload and show images on the same page.

```
<?php
// Connection To Database
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "my_db";
$connection = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname);
if (!$connection)
{
die('Could Not Connect To Database: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
mysqli_query($connection, "SET NAMES utf8");

// Garb User Account Details
$garb = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM my_table");
if(!$garb){
$error = "<div class='error'>There's Little Problem: ".mysql_error()."</div>";
} else {
//Showing The User Data
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($garb)) {
  $A_Id = $row['A_Id'];
  $A_ProfilePic = $row['A_ProfilePic'];
}


// Getting Image
$A_ProfilePic = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['A_ProfilePic']['tmp_name'])); //SQL Injection defence!
$A_ProfilePic = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $A_ProfilePic);


//Everything Is Okay So Let's Register This User
$update = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE accounts SET A_ProfilePic='$A_ProfilePic' WHERE A_Id='999999'");
if(!$update){
$updateerror = "<div class='error'>There's Little Problem: ".mysql_error()."</div>";
} else {
//Confirming Message To User
$error = "<div class='success'>Your Pic Is Updated.</div><br/>";
}
?>

/* Getting Image */
<?php echo '<img class="profileAvatar" alt="" title="" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($A_ProfilePic).'"/>';?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="A_ProfilePic" id="A_ProfilePic"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Your Setting"></input>
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset Form"></input>
</form>
```

But I am getting the error as when inserting the image then my Base64 code is not perfectly inserted that why while retrieving images am not able to see it. I converted the same image from online Base64 converter then got different code from my database code. So whats the error...???

Comment: Your'e double escaping with `addslashes()` and then `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.  Just use a prepared statement and stop doing that.

Comment: I tried one also but not working...

Comment: The ones that are inserted are already screwed up with double escapes and if you escape it before displaying it won't be corret.

Comment: Means what to do...??? Can you explain in term of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working by using the below codes that is nearly same as above but have some changing. Now from this code I am able to change and view image on runtime on a single page.

```
<?php
// Connection To Database
$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "my_db";
$connection = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname);
if (!$connection)
{
die('Could Not Connect To Database: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
mysqli_query($connection, "SET NAMES utf8");

// Garb User Account Details
$garb = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM my_table");
if(!$garb){
$error = "<div class='error'>There's Little Problem: ".mysql_error()."</div>";
} else {
//Showing The User Data
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($garb)) {
  $A_Id = $row['A_Id'];
  $A_ProfilePic = $row['A_ProfilePic'];
}

// Update Image In Database
if (isset($_POST['A_ProfilePic'])){
// Getting Image
$A_ProfilePic_Add = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $A_ProfilePic);
//Everything Is Okay So Let's Register This User
$update = mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE accounts SET A_ProfilePic='$A_ProfilePic_Add' WHERE A_Id='999999'");
if(!$update){
$updateerror = "<div class='error'>There's Little Problem: ".mysql_error()."</div>";
} else {
//Confirming Message To User
$error = "<div class='success'>Your Pic Is Updated.</div><br/>";
}
header("Refresh:0");
}
?>

/* Getting Image */
<?php echo '<img class="profileAvatar" alt="" title="" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($A_ProfilePic).'"/>';?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="A_ProfilePic" id="A_ProfilePic"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Your Setting"></input>
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset Form"></input>
</form>
```